# css drop down menu :: sub menu is appearing within main menu after hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i have written a css code for my drop down menu

**PROBLEMS WITH MY DROP DOWN MENU ARE ::**

1. when i hover on my main menu item(i.e. in the exapmle 2nd one "bbbbb") it displays the submenu...thats ok..but its appearing with in the main menu by increaing its height
2. the background of main menu becomes the background of sub menu too,obviously i dont want that
3. in main menu list items starts with lot of text-inedent,i dont want that
4. text are aligned right in submenu
5. i want content width for sub menu not more than that

MY HTML ::

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">bbbbbbbbbb</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">bbbbbbbbbb</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my css::

```
.menu{
   width:70%;
   overflow:hidden;
   background:green;
   position:relative;
 }
.menu ul{list-style:none;}
.menu ul li{ margin-left:20px;position:relative; float:left}
.menu ul ul{display:none;}
.menu ul li:hover ul{display:block; background:black;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li{ float:none;}
```

and please explain my mistake

**[HERE IS MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32bpr/4/)**

Comment: @syedmohsin it will be great if you explain the changes..what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make some changes in the code. 
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32bpr/5/)**
css

```
.menu{
 width:70%;
 background:green;
 position:relative;
 }
.menu ul{list-style:none;}
.menu ul li{ margin-left:20px;position:relative; float:left}
.menu ul ul{display:none;}
.menu ul li:hover ul{display:block; background:black;
position: absolute; margin: -2px 0 0 0; z-index: 11110;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li{ float:none; height:20px; }
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32bpr/6/)**
**Changes:** 
*display: inline-block;* occupies the combined width of the inner container.
*position:relative;* using it in menu will cause increase in the height of the outer container.
you can read it at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: thanks for your response..but as you can see now the green background of main menu is vanished in your fiddle...

Comment: this was nice..i accepted it...but it will be great if you expain the changes..why to use them..thanks  @syed

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/vcMtv/2/

```
.menu{
width:70%;
overflow:hidden;
background:green;
position:relative;
 }
.menu ul{list-style:none;}
.menu ul li{ margin-left:20px;position:relative; float:left}
.menu ul ul{display:none;}
.menu ul li:hover ul{display:block; background:black;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li{ float:none;}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer...a little change i need in your css...i dont need that gray background of main menu's list item

Comment: how to remove that..and what was my mistake please explain